# Word.InsertLocation.Replace is not working for content control

Tags: office365, office-js, cpu-word

In browser `contentcontrol.inserttext("text", Word.InsertLocation.Replace)` not working fine it always concatenate the string in the start ideally it should replace the old text inside the content control with the new text. Is there any other work-around to replace the text inside a content control. (specially for windows)

Comment: I tried on on word desktop(version:2012, build 13519.20000) with scriptlab gist: https://gist.github.com/MandytMSFT/e03f318df85c10d23b4d9c88915ce33c , it works well. Could you share more details like your word version or code details ?

Comment: yup it's working fine on desktop but it's not working on browser.i am sharing a link please find the attached video.https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1516